# Monitor WebSphere Application Server console with JVisualVM

Tags: java, websphere, jvisualvm

I am running several applications in IBM WebSphere Application Server (WAS) 7. The applications can be managed from the WAS console: http://{myserver}:9060/ibm/console/login.do

I am able to monitor those deployed applications with JVisualVM. How can I monitor the WAS console with JVisualVM. Does it have a default JMX port?

Comment: Why do you want monitor that application? And what would you like to monitor? It is system application.

Comment: I am getting OutOfMemory (Java heap memory) every 5 days or so. I am afraid the WAS console has a memory leak.

Comment: Its rather your app that has memory leak. Enable verbose gc logging in the server, and also generate a few heap dumps. Then you can use tools in the IBM Support Assistant (downloadable for free) to compare heap dumps and find your leak.